# Output code not highlighted when used as input

Tags: front-end, syntax-highlighting

#### I have reported this issue: [CASE:3389542]

---

Today, I accidentally found what I believe is an unwanted feature of the front-end, where input code is not appropriately highlighted and the dynamic highlighting of e.g. matching braces doesn't work.

Very simple example:

```
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {2, 2}]] // InputForm
```

This gives as expected an ouput-cell that contains code

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, I have three choices when I want to edit this code

- just go inside the output cell and start typing
- use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to *Copy output from above* into a new input cell
- copy the cell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and paste it

When I use the first method, I noticed that highlighting and brace matching doesn't work. The same is true for the second method **iff** you go under the output cell *without* creating a new input cell (by pressing a key and deleting the char for instance).

The code looks then like this, where you should note the missing highlighting of the option strings:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Can someone confirm this behavior? I have seen it on Linux and Mac OS X both running 10.2.

Note, I have not described the issue extensively. For instance the underlying cell-expressions look different for copy&paste code compared to *Copy output from above* code. I hope the issue is described in enough detail to reproduce it at WRI.

Comment: I see it on 10.1 and 9.0.1, Mac OS X.

Answer (score 5):

It has been like this for a long time, hasn't it?  At least since version 7.  I always assumed that `InputForm` (the Head, not the format) wasn't really intended for reentry, though since it does mostly work I guess it should work completely.  Most of the time I just let the output render, select it, and use the menu command: **Cell** > **Convert To** > **InputForm** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>).

As has been noted by Alexey Popkov before using another head around `InputForm` produces a different formatting, one that you would seem to prefer, so you might use:

```
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {2, 2}]] // InputForm // DisplayForm
```

You may also consider `PlainForm` or `CodeForm` from the GeneralUtilities package:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {2, 2}]] // PlainForm
```

Comment: When used with `Ctrl+Shift+L` for *insert output from above*, the only thing that works is `//InputForm//DisplayForm`. `Plainform` doesn't and returns the same [non-highlighting input like here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GgtOC.png), except when I go directly in the output and convert it to "InputForm" with `Ctrl+Shift+I`.

Comment: @halirutan `PlainForm` appears to work correctly with Ctrl+Shift+L in 10.1 under Windows, e.g. `Hold[Solve[y = x, y]] // PlainForm` then Ctrl+Shift+L shows expected syntax highlighting.  Can you give me a counterexample?

Comment: It seems I mixed something up because the coloring is OK. But did you noticed that strings are turned into *fake symbols*?? [Look here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt6vK.png) where `"QuasiNewton"` seems to by symbolized. It is still a string and you see this the first time you hit a key in this new cell :-)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that a cell made with <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> has form

```
Cell[BoxData["...", "Output", "Input", FormatType -> "InputForm"]
```

The code editor only likes cells with the form

```
Cell[BoxData["..." , "Input"]
```

If you were to open the cell with Cell > Show Expression (<kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) edit to remove `"Output"`, and `FormatType -> "InputForm"`, all would be well. Of course, you shouldn't have to do that.

Clearly, the <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> should behave more intelligently.

Comment: On Linux with version 10.2 I see something [completely different](http://i.stack.imgur.com/p1ilU.png). No `BoxData` and not `FormatType` for me. Anyway, it's something that should work and that we cannot fix ourselves. It's not even a big issue, but I'm kind of pedantic when it comes to UI and usability.

Comment: @halirutan. I am running 10.1 on OS X. I'm surprised that you see such a different cell form. But I'm entirely with you on UI usability.

Comment: On Windows 7 x64 with version 10.2 I see the same [as @halirutan](http://i.stack.imgur.com/p1ilU.png): no `BoxData` and `FormatType`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the conversation I had with the support. First response from support@wolfram.com

> Using InputForm returns an expression suitable for input, so when you change it it becomes an input expression. Please useToString to generate a string in input form:
>
> ```
> ToString[ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {2, 2}]], InputForm]
> ```
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]

---

That indeed did not help me because my question was a different one. Therefore, I tried to explain it further

> Hi [name],
>
> I don't want to create a string in `InputForm`. There seems to be a bug in the
>   front end that makes that code is not properly highlighted when you use 
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to insert ouput code from above that was displayed as `InputForm`. Please evaluate the following code (that is held with `Hold` and does nothing) and especially pay attention to the green coloring of local variables and the gray coloring
>   of the option string:
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> After you have evaluated this, please press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to insert the output as new input.
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> Do you see that all the code highlighting is gone (no green, no gray anymore)?
>
> Btw, if you would have used the combination `//InputForm//DisplayForm`, then fully highlighted code is inserted by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
>
> With this in mind, would you please consider re-reading the detailed [post here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88805/187) and rethink whether it should be marked a bug in your database?

---

Here is the answer from yesterday

> This looks as a as-designed feature that's also explained in the documentation pages of `InputForm` and `DisplayForm`; `InputForm` prints all you need to be able to evaluate an expression (1D form) but DisplayForm prints also all the you need to show it as the front end would (2D form). However, I have passed along your comments/explanation to our developer team for further consideration.

I cannot say that I agree with this because (let's concentrate on this one) when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to insert the last output, you intend to use it as input and input should be properly highlighted. Beside, there is a major point: When I already created a new input cell by typing anything (for instance `()` and going inside the braces) and I use *then* *Insert Output from Above*, look what happens (especially pay attention that I used the evil `InputForm`):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell) generated using the [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) wrapper:

```
a + b //InputForm
```

> Cell["a + b", "Output",
>    CellChangeTimes->{{3.747528582367461*^9, 3.747528588598588*^9}, 3.747528677164525*^9},
>    CellLabel->"Out[186]//InputForm="]

versus the [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell) contents of the input "a+b"

> Cell[BoxData[
>    RowBox[{"a", "+", "b"}]], "Input",
>    CellChangeTimes->{{3.74752883542157*^9, 3.747528837893704*^9}}]

The key difference is that the [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) output uses a string instead of a [`BoxData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxData) as the first argument. Since the argument is a string, 2D editing is disallowed, and because it is a string, syntax coloring doesn't work.

Using [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) + [`DisplayForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayForm) as suggested by MrWizard produces a different kind of cell:

```
a + b //InputForm //DisplayForm
```

> Cell[BoxData[
>    TagBox[
>     InterpretationBox[
>      StyleBox[
>       RowBox[{"a", " ", "+", " ", "b"}],
>       ShowStringCharacters->True,
>       NumberMarks->True],
>      InputForm[\$CellContext`a + $CellContext`b],
>      AutoDelete->True,
>      Editable->True],
>     DisplayForm]], "Output",
>    CellChangeTimes->{3.747529163398923*^9},
>    CellLabel->"Out[190]//DisplayForm="]

Notice how the cell now contains a [`BoxData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxData) wrapper (as well as boxes, but that difference isn't relevant) with lots of wrappers. I don't like this approach because the boxes become rather unwieldy after 2D editing. For example, placing the cursor after the `b` and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> produces the following cell:

> Cell[BoxData[
>    TagBox[
>     RowBox[{
>      StyleBox["a",
>       ShowStringCharacters->True,
>       NumberMarks->True], 
>      StyleBox[" ",
>       ShowStringCharacters->True,
>       NumberMarks->True], 
>      StyleBox["+",
>       ShowStringCharacters->True,
>       NumberMarks->True], 
>      StyleBox[" ",
>       ShowStringCharacters->True,
>       NumberMarks->True], 
>      SuperscriptBox[
>       StyleBox["b",
>        ShowStringCharacters->True,
>        NumberMarks->True], "\[Placeholder]"]}],
>     DisplayForm]], "Input",
>    CellChangeTimes->{{3.747529388438327*^9, 3.747529388455496*^9}}]

Notice the proliferation of [`StyleBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleBox) wrappers that appears.

My suggestion is to create a new form that uses a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox), as this will prevent the proliferation of [`StyleBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleBox) wrappers:

```
MakeBoxes[myInputForm[expr_], StandardForm] ^:= With[
    {arg = MakeBoxes[InputForm[expr]][[1,1]]},
    TemplateBox[{arg},
        "myInputForm",
        DisplayFunction -> (StyleBox[#,ShowStringCharacters->True,NumberMarks->True]&),
        InterpretationFunction->(#&)
    ]
]
```

`myInputForm` produces the following cell:

```
Hold[f[x_] := a + b] //myInputForm
```

> Cell[BoxData[
>    TemplateBox[{"Hold[f[x_] := a + b]"},
>     "myInputForm",
>     DisplayFunction->(StyleBox[#, ShowStringCharacters -> True, NumberMarks -> True]& ),
>     InterpretationFunction->(#& )]], "Output",
>    CellChangeTimes->{3.7475298985844793`*^9},
>    CellLabel->"Out[196]="]

If we place the cursor after the `b` this time, and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> we get:

> Cell[BoxData[
>    TemplateBox[{RowBox[{"Hold", "[", 
>        RowBox[{
>          RowBox[{"f", "[", "x_", "]"}], " ", ":=", " ", 
>          RowBox[{"a", " ", "+", " ", 
>            SuperscriptBox["b", "\[Placeholder]"]}]}], "]"}]},
>     "myInputForm",
>     DisplayFunction->(StyleBox[#, ShowStringCharacters -> True, NumberMarks -> True]& ),
>     InterpretationFunction->(#& )]], "Input",
>    CellChangeTimes->{{3.7475300096828337`*^9, 3.747530009698186*^9}}]

Notice that the argument of the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) has changed from a string to boxes automatically, and the [`StyleBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleBox) proliferation we saw earlier is absent. Also, since we have a [`BoxData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxData) object, and the cell style has changed to "Input", the above cell has syntax coloring as desired. Here is a screen shot of the above rendered cell:

[image]